# primeNG programmatically change tab when using *ngFor on tabPanel

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to programmatically change to the next tab whenever the user creates a new tab. However, I can't get it to work. I saw a [github discussion](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4530) indicating that I should still be using the `[selected]` input on the repeated `<p-tabPanel>` element but I can't seem to get it right. I end up getting this error for `TabPanel.html:2` when creating another tab.

`Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.`

template code:

```
<p-tabView  [controlClose]="true" (onClose)="deletePiece($event)" [activeIndex]="selectedTabIndex">
    <p-tabPanel [header]="'Piece ' + i" *ngFor="let piece of pieceCollection; let i = index" [closable]="true" [selected]="i == selectedTabIndex" (click)="setSelectedTabIndex(i)">
        {{ tabContent }}
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

edit: added the code for changing a tab. I just push a new element to my `pieceCollection` and update the value of `selectedTabIndex`:

```
addNewPiece() {
    if (this.canCreateNewPiece){
        this.pieceCollection.push(new RequestPiece());
        this.selectedTabIndex = this.pieceCollection.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you change tab?

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes i added the code. i just increment `selectedTabIndex`

Comment: Try setting the tab index asynchronously: `setTimeout(() => { this.selectedTabIndex = this.pieceCollection.length; }, 0);`. I am also wondering if that index is correct, or if you should use `this.pieceCollection.length - 1`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan okay, interesting! not only was my index wrong (should have been length-1), but it didn't work correctly until I put it in the timeout. Good call, thank you!

Comment: @ConnorsFan would you like to copy/paste your comment as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: You are welcome. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two things you can change in `addNewPiece`:

- Set the index to `this.pieceCollection.length - 1` instead of `this.pieceCollection.length`
- Set the index asynchronously, or force change detection before setting the index, to avoid the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

**Method 1 - Setting the index asynchronously**

```
addNewPiece() {
    if (this.canCreateNewPiece){
        this.pieceCollection.push(new RequestPiece());
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.selectedTabIndex = this.pieceCollection.length - 1;
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

**Method 2 - Triggering change detection before setting the index**

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, ...) { }

addNewPiece() {
    if (this.canCreateNewPiece){
        this.pieceCollection.push(new RequestPiece());
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.selectedTabIndex = this.pieceCollection.length - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added another method to avoid the exception when setting the tab index.